# regex expression with multiple patterns in a given character vector

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a string (x, see below) that has many different formats.  They are all positions on a genome but have different names.  These names were given to me and belong to a list of about 6 million so it's not easy for me to change manually.  This is a subset, however there are others like X1 or chr 13 that are part of this list too.:

```
 x <- c("rs62224609.16051249.T.C", "rs376238049.16052962.C.T","rs62224614.16053862.C.T","X22.17028719.G.A", "rs4535153", "X22.17028719.G.A", "kgp3171179", "rs375850426.17029070.GCAGTGGC.G"  , "chr22.17030620.G.A")
```

I'd like all the string to look like this:

```
 y <- c("rs62224609", "rs376238049", "rs62224614", "chr22:17028719", "rs4535153", "chr22:17028719", "kgp3171179", "rs375850426", "chr22:17030620")
```

I've tried the following, but everything after the first "." is removed... which isn't exactly what I want.

```
x.test = gsub(pattern = "\\.\\S+$", replacement = "", x = x)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what distinguishes `"X22.17028719.G.A"` -> `"chr22:17028719"` from `"rs62224609.16051249.T.C"` -> `"rs62224609"` Please edit the original question with supplementary information.

Comment: Yes, can you explain why `"X22.17028719.G.A"` becomes `""chr22:17028719"`? Are there any other prefixes like `X22` that need to be replaced like this, or can you just replace all instances of `X22.` with `chr22:`?

Comment: Thanks for your questions!  Yes, I could but I'm trying to automate because there are also X1, X2... all the way to X22. There are no other prefixes other than X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your data corresponds to the examples you've given:

```
x = c("rs62224609.16051249.T.C", "rs376238049.16052962.C.T","rs62224614.16053862.C.T","X22.17028719.G.A", "rs4535153", "X22.17028719.G.A", "kgp3171179", "rs375850426.17029070.GCAGTGGC.G"  , "chr22.17030620.G.A")
```

There are two types of ids, the ones with SNP ids (starting with rs or kgp), and the ones giving a chromosomal position (starting with the chromosome name).
You could start off by identifying your SNP ids, with something like:

```
x1 = gsub("((rs|kgp)\\d+).*","\\1",x)
```

This returns:

```
[1] "rs62224609"     "rs376238049"    "rs62224614"     "X22.17028719.G.A"   "rs4535153"     "X22.17028719.G.A"   "kgp3171179"     "rs375850426"     "chr22.17030620.G.A"
```

Then format the chromosome positions with (I've assumed that you had chromosomes from 1 to 22, X,Y and M, but this depends on your data):

```
## We look for [(chr OR X) (1 or 2 digits or X or Y or M) 1 or more punctuation marks (1 or more digits) anything] and 
## we transform it into: [chr (the second captured element) : (the third captured element)]
x2 = gsub("(chr|X)(\\d{1,2}|X|Y|M)[[:punct:]]+(\\d+).*","chr\\2:\\3",x1)
```

This returns:

```
[1] "rs62224609"     "rs376238049"    "rs62224614"     "chr22:17028719" "rs4535153"      "chr22:17028719"   "kgp3171179"     "rs375850426"    "chr22:17030620"
```

Comment: Hi @Lamia.  Another quick question for you...suppose I have a list of SNPs that look like this test <- c('psy_rs1806509_C','psy_rs18350409_TTA').
How would I pop off the last _and the character string after?

Comment: If you do `gsub("((rs|kgp)\\d+).*","\\1",c('psy_rs1806509_C','psy_rs18350409_TTA'))`, it returns "psy_rs1806509"  "psy_rs18350409". Isn't this what you want?